# How is possible create more than one Table Of Content (TOC) in my PDF document with mpdf?

Tags: php, mpdf

Well I'm doing a project based in mpdf library, and I was trying to create more than one TOC in my document, I'm looking for the possibility to do it because I need create a new TOC to represent figures in my document so I was reading the documentation and it explained that from 2.3 version is possible create more than one TOC using $name, well this is the problem I am assuming that in the tags  you can put names in that way:

```
<tocpagebreak name="table1" paging="on" links="on" toc-preHTML="&lt;h2 class=&quot;centrar datosMonitoreo negrilla&quot;&gt;GENERAL INDEX&lt;/h2&gt;" pagenumstyle="A" toc-pagenumstyle="1"/>
<tocpagebreak name="table2" paging="on" links="on" toc-preHTML="&lt;h2 class=&quot;centrar datosMonitoreo negrilla&quot;&gt;TEST&lt;/h2&gt;" toc-pagenumstyle="1" />
```

But when I tried to watch the result throught my xampp server the tables dissapear only the title keeps, what's more, when I put *name* in just one *tocpagebreak* tag the table dissapear.

When I did the first table and didn't put name in the tag all generated so good, but I need watch the next table, so I will be grateful to hear your suggestions for moving forward.

I was reading the documentation, search similar question here or examples in the web to try solving.

Mainly I'd the content in this way:

```
<div>
      <tocpagebreak name="table1" paging="on" links="on" toc-preHTML="&lt;h2 class=&quot;centrar datosMonitoreo negrilla&quot;&gt;GENERAL INDEX&lt;/h2&gt;" pagenumstyle="A" toc-pagenumstyle="1"/>
      <tocpagebreak name="table2" paging="on" links="on" toc-preHTML="&lt;h2 class=&quot;centrar datosMonitoreo negrilla&quot;&gt;TEST&lt;/h2&gt;" toc-pagenumstyle="1" />
</div>
```

I was trying to separate in different div's but nothing happens and I erase the second tag and trying to put name in the first one bue the table disappear as well.